# Report column is showing #Error when using Subscriptions

Tags: subscription, ssrs-2017

As titled, when using SSRS 2017 subscriptions to generate a report, a column with expression is showing #Error. However, when I try to run manual in web and in the report builder, it can be shown.

The Expression is:
`=Code.Decode(Fields!Comments.Value)`

The function is:

```
Function Decode(ByVal EncodedString AS String) AS String

    Return System.Web.HttpUtility.HTMLDecode(EncodedString)

End Function
```

Any suggestion or help will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem by myself. Use the following method instead

```
Function Decode(ByVal EncodedString AS String) AS String
   Return System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(EncodedString)
End Function
```